# Regular expression: matching multiple words

Tags: regex, r

I am using regular expressions in R to extract strings from a variable. The variable contains distinct values that look like:

MEDIUM /REGULAR INSEAM

XX LARGE /SHORT INSEAM

SMALL /32" INSM

X LARGE /30" INSM

I have to capture two things: the value before the `/`  as a whole(SMALL,XX LARGE) and the string(alphabetic or numeric) after it. I dont want the `" INSM` or the `INSEAM` part.

The regular expression for first two I am using is `([A-Z]\w+) \/([A-Z]\w+) INSEAM` and for the last two I am using `([A-Z]\w+) \/([0-9][0-9])[" INSM]`.
The part `([A-Z]\w+)` only captures one word, so it works fine for MEDIUM and SMALL, but fails for X LARGE, XX LARGE etc. Is there a way I can modify it to capture two occurances of word before the `/` character? Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [`(\w+(?: \w+)?) *\/ *(\w+"?(?: \w+)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/zA3bA8/1)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but it also captures the INSM/INSEAM part. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: So, even simpler [`(\w+(?: \w+)?) *\/ *(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/zA3bA8/3) might do?

Comment: Your description says 'the value before the /', but your regex doesn't reflect that. I get the correct output with `sub("^(.* /\\w+).*", "\\1", x)`

Comment: @PierreLafortune: I think *I have to capture two things* is relevant here.

Comment: @PierreLafortune the value before / can be one string or two strings as given in the examples. Wiktor: thank you! it worked.

Comment: If that is the case, then my regex will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use

```
(\w+(?: \w+)?) */ *(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV3mH0/1)

*Pattern details*:

- `(\w+(?: \w+)?)` - Group 1 capturing one or more word chars followed with an optional sequence of a space + one or more word chars
- `*/ *` - a `/` enclosed with 0+ spaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more word chars

R code with `stringr`:

```
> library(stringr)
> v <- c("MEDIUM /REGULAR INSEAM", "XX LARGE /SHORT INSEAM", "SMALL /32\" INSM", "X LARGE /30\" INSM")
> str_match(v, "(\\w+(?: \\w+)?) */ *(\\w+)")
     [,1]              [,2]       [,3]     
[1,] "MEDIUM /REGULAR" "MEDIUM"   "REGULAR"
[2,] "XX LARGE /SHORT" "XX LARGE" "SHORT"  
[3,] "SMALL /32"       "SMALL"    "32"     
[4,] "X LARGE /30"     "X LARGE"  "30"
```

Answer (score 2):

From your description, Wiktor's regex will fail on `"XX  LARGE/SHORT"` due to the extra space. It is safer to capture everything before the forward slash as a group:

```
sub("^(.*/\\w+).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "MEDIUM /REGULAR"  "XX  LARGE /SHORT" "SMALL /32" "X LARGE /30"
```